# How to find the unusual character ' using POSIX in bash?

Tags: bash, find

here are some names:

El Peulo'Pasa, Van O'Driscoll, Mike_Willam

how to filter the name contains ', using POSIX in bash by command find?

if I use the following command,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -regex '^.*[']*$' -print
```

Bash runs into a problem because the syntax ' will automatically convert the input to string

Comment: `-regex "^.*['].*$"` -- you need a second `.` before the second `*`; you want the `*` to modify a `.`, not to modify `[']`.

Comment: "will automatically convert the input to string" makes no sense. _Everything_ is a string in bash unless you go far out of your way to make it otherwise. `-print` is a string (and it's 100% identical to `"-print"` or `'-print'` or `"-"'p'rint`; `find` can't tell which of those you used, they're completely interchangeable). `-regex` is a string. It's not unusual or surprising or wrong for things to be strings; it's unusual for things _not_ to be strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `-regex` ([which is a non-POSIX action](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)) for this at all; `-name` is more than adequate. (`-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` are also extensions that aren't present in the POSIX standard).

To make a `'` literal, put it inside double quotes, or in an unquoted context and precede it with a backslash:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -name "*'*" -print
```

...or the 100% identical but harder-to-read command line...

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -name '*'\''*' -print
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just searching the current directory (and not its subdirectories), you don't even need `find`, just a wildcard ("glob") expression:

```
ls *\'*
```

(Note that the `'` must be escaped or double-quoted, but the asterisks must not be.)

If you want to do operations on these files, you can either use that wildcard expression directly:

```
dosomethingwith *\'*
# or
for file in *\'*; do
    dosomethingwith "$file"
done
```

...or if you're using bash, store the filenames in an array, then use that. This involves getting the quoting just right, to avoid trouble with other weird characters in filenames (e.g. spaces):

```
filelist=( *\'* )
dosomethingwith "${filelist[@]}"
# or
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    dosomethingwith "$file"
done
```

The note here is that arrays are *not* part of the POSIX shell standard; they work in some shells (bash, ksh, zsh, etc), but not in others (e.g. dash). If you want to use arrays, be sure to use the right shebang to get the shell you want (and don't override it by running the script with `sh scriptname`).